# Getting ViewBag at OnResultExecuted Filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'd like to get `ViewBag` at `OnResultExecuted` filter. Both

```
((ViewResultBase)filterContext.Result).ViewBag.Get
```

and

```
filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.Get
```

returns `ViewBag` assigned at action. But I'd like to get `ViewBag` assigned at "view.cshtml".
What I want to acheve is getting `ViewBag`.Title from razor

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "My Title";
}
```

And then, writing it to end of response text as a javascript. This is useful at `@Ajax.ActionLink()` situations. My `OnActionExecuted` filter code must be so:

```
string scriptText = "<script type='text/javascript'>document.title = '" + ViewBag.Title + "';</script>";
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Write(scriptText);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This means that you know the right answer. If so you can reply my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass values from view to controller. It is basically against the MVC pattern. When the view is executed it gets own copy of `ViewData` (`ViewBag`) so any changes to it are valid only in the scope of the view.

**From Scott Guthrie's blog:**

> Views should not contain any application logic or database retrieval
>   code, instead all application/data logic should only be handled by the
>   controller class.  The motivation behind this partitioning is to help
>   enforce a clear separation of your application/data logic from your UI
>   generation code.  This makes it easier to unit test your
>   application/data logic in isolation from your UI rendering logic.
>
> Views should only render their output using the view-specific data
>   passed to it by the Controller class.  In the ASP.NET MVC Framework we
>   call this view-specific data "ViewData".  The rest of this blog post
>   is going to cover some of the different approaches you can use to pass
>   this "ViewData" from the Controller to the View to render.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/06/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-3-passing-viewdata-from-controllers-to-views.aspx

Similar question with explanations is also here: [Setting ViewData item in a Partial to be read in a View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131160/setting-viewdata-item-in-a-partial-to-be-read-in-a-view)

So closer to your question. You cannot pass the value of Title to your action execution filter and you have to resolve it at the scope of the controller.

Comment: I have reread again your question and deleted my comments with suggestions because now I feel I do not understand your requirements well. What's that javascript for? Why are you setting title with js? Is your intention to change document.title by clicking on the @Ajax.ActionLink you mentioned?

Comment: Yes, When you click on Ajax.ActionLink(), document title isn't changed. I'd like it to be changed automatically.

Comment: Ok, please post it as new question - How to update Html document title with @Ajax.ActionLink - so others could also suggest solution for you (I have also one on my mind)

Comment: Please refer to this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494707/how-to-update-html-document-title-with-ajax-actionlink