# How to update Html document title with @Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

When an Ajax.ActionLink is clicked, I'd like page title to change automatically according to ViewBag.Title. I could do, but I cannot access ViewBag.Title assigned at "razor.cshtml" file from ActionExecutedFilter. I can access ViewBag.Title only assigned at Action Method from ActionExecutedFilter.

The ActionExecutedFilter could be so:

```
string scriptText = "<script type='text/javascript'>document.title = '" 
                    + ViewBag.Title + "';</script>";
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Write(scriptText);
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Don't you consider using jquery to request an action and get a `json`  object to update your `UpdateTargetId `  element you have setted on `Ajax.ActionLink` and apply anoter property of json object to `document.title`?

Comment: The way I have specified above more attractive, If I can do from filters.

Comment: You can't do the way you show your code. When you make an ajax request, your result will most likely be either a JSON or HTML view. You need to capture the OnSuccess event and update your page title with the result set you got from your action.
You need to review how MVC works, there are some fundamental flaws in what you're attempting.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could solve your problem. However it is not using the ViewBag, but the value of the title will be also tied to your partial view file and if I understand it well it is your intention.

**Your partial view**

```
<span id="mySpan" style="display:none">Page header</span>
@Ajax.ActionLink("MyLink", "Random", 
                 new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", 
                                     UpdateTargetId = "random", 
                                     OnSuccess = "document.title = document.getElementById('mySpan').innerHTML" 
                  });

<div id="random">
    Random goes here.
</div>
```

The value you want to set from your partial view to document title is hidden inside the span (it could be also value of some header `<h1/>` or subheader `<h2/>` ... depends on your needs).